# Converting large SQLite tables to XML

Tags: java, xml, sqlite

I am trying to convert a large (-ish) table into XML. for that purpose I am using DOM Parser, based on how [Mkyong does here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-create-xml-file-in-java-dom/).

This works fine for smaller tables, but I'm having trouble with a table with 7 columns and about 3.5 million rows. It just takes forever. Could you suggest a better method or point out where I could improve my code?

I am not allowed to use anything but Java and/or SQLite. Maybe i have not searched with the right keywords, but google didn't turn up anything good so far.

```
public class Export {

public static void export() {
    String select = "Select * FROM individuen ORDER BY ID";
    DBController dbc = DBController.getInstance();
    dbc.initDBConnection();

    try {
        Statement stmt = DBController.connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(select);
        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        // root elements
        Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
        Element rootElement = doc.createElement("individuen");
        doc.appendChild(rootElement);

        while (rs.next()) {
            Element person = doc.createElement("Person");
            rootElement.appendChild(person);

            // set attribute to person element
            Attr attr = doc.createAttribute("id");
            attr.setValue(Integer.toString(rs.getInt(1)));
            person.setAttributeNode(attr);

            Element geschlecht = doc.createElement("Geschlecht");
            geschlecht.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(Integer.toString(rs.getInt(2))));
            person.appendChild(geschlecht);

            [...]
        }

        System.out.println("oooooooooooout");
        // write the content into xml file
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("file.xml"));

        // Output to console for testing
        // StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);

        transformer.transform(source, result);

        System.out.println("Als XML exportiert!");

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
        pce.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TransformerException tfe) {
        tfe.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Why bother with a full XML DOM that is, in effect, "write only".  Forget the XML libraries and write out the XML directly via String manipulation.  Your code will be a bit longer but you're pulling a ton of data into memory that you're only going to write out and never interact with.

Comment: Since you are dealing with a lot of data, I suggest you **not to** use DOM. It's just not effcient enough. Use SAX/StAX directly, or, directly build the XML file with InputStream(or channels if you want NIO). You may also split all your work into pieces and write segments of xml concurrently (you may try the Fork/Join framework) and combine them all into one document. Anyway, xml isn't that suitable for storing large database. Its size, maintainablilty and speed of processing really stops your world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your tips, I went with SAX/StAX and it's working fine now. Here is part of the code for anybody who might be looking for something similar:

```
public void export(Population pop) {
    String select = "Select * FROM individuen ORDER BY ID";
    DBController dbc = DBController.getInstance();
    dbc.initDBConnection();

    XMLOutputFactory factory = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
    XMLStreamWriter writer;

    try {
        Statement stmt = DBController.connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(select);
        writer = factory.createXMLStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("output.xml"));

        // Creating the XML-Header
        writer.writeStartDocument();
        // Root Element
        writer.writeStartElement("individuen");
        while (rs.next()) {

            // Element Person, encompasses the other Elements
            writer.writeStartElement("Peron");
            writer.writeAttribute("ID", rs.getString(1));

            // Element Geschlecht
            writer.writeStartElement("Geschlecht");
            writer.writeCharacters(rs.getString(2));
            writer.writeEndElement();

            // Element Alter
            writer.writeStartElement("Alter");
            writer.writeCharacters(rs.getString(3));
            writer.writeEndElement();

            // Element Alter
            writer.writeStartElement("Familienstand");
            writer.writeCharacters(rs.getString(4));
            writer.writeEndElement();

            // Element PartnerID
            writer.writeStartElement("PartnerID");
            writer.writeCharacters(rs.getString(4));
            writer.writeEndElement();

            // Element Bildungsstand
            writer.writeStartElement("Bildungsstand");
            writer.writeCharacters(rs.getString(5));
            writer.writeEndElement();

            // Closes Element Person
            writer.writeEndElement();
        }
        writer.writeEndDocument();
        writer.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```